# Promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I have problem in my javascript code
I want to swal a message then back to top But this swal and back to top same time, then this again to last position. How i can do it. Sorry for my english

```
promise.then(function(){
    swal({
      title: "Ok",

      type: "success",
      confirmButtonText: "Close"
    });
})
.then(function(){
       $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 700);
})
```

Comment: can you post your complete code,

Comment: It is hard to understand your question.  Please post a link to which library you are using `swal()` from so we can see the doc for that library and explain the context.  Are you using it with angular?  Are you trying to get the animation to happen AFTER the user hits a button in the `swal()`?  Is your problem that the animation happens to soon?

Comment: The `swal()` code I see does not return a promise so it will not be timing compatible with promises without putting it in a promise wrapper and then returning that promise in your `.then()` handler.  Also, please show the code that creates `promise` in case there are issues there too.

Comment: Seems like if you pass a function as second argument to swal, it will be called right after the first message is closed, so you can put your jQuery code there. Check: t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Comment: Thank all for reply. My code is `https://jsfiddle.net/zzxme9fc/1/` i want after i click ok then scroll to top, how i do it

Comment: Thank all very much, i read again docs and this work fine.

Comment: This will help you understand the usage of Promises which would be useful in future :) https://www.sitepoint.com/overview-javascript-promises/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `swal()` does not appear to return a promise, it seems you should just use the normal callback mechanism that `swal()` supports:

```
swal({
  title: "Ok",
  type: "success",
  confirmButtonText: "Close"
}, function() {
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 700);
});
```

If you wanted to make a promise wrapper for `swal()`, you could do that like this:

```
function swalP(options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        swal(options, resolve);
    });
}
```

Then, you could use:

```
swalP({
  title: "Ok",
  type: "success",
  confirmButtonText: "Close"
}).then(function() {
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 700);
});
```